# Entity Framework - Add reference to abstract navigation property without loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Adding a reference to a non-abstract navigation property is fine:

```
class Entity {
    int Id { get; set; }

    Reference Reference { get; set; }
    Parent Other { get; set; }
}

class Reference {
    int Id { get; set; }
}

abstract class Parent {
    int Id { get; set; }
}

class Child : Parent { }

async Task DbMethod() {
    using(var context = new XYZDbContext()) {
        var reference = new Reference { Id = 6 };
        context.Attach(reference);

        var entity = new Entity {
            Id = 3,
            Reference = reference,
        };

        context.Add(entity);

        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

But if I wanted to set the `Other` property to an existing record (say id 42), I can't instantiate the `Parent` class (as it's abstract) like I do with the `Reference` class.

How would I add a reference to an existing entity for the abstract `Parent` class? I imagine that I could add a `OtherId` property to the `Entity` class and set that, but I'd like to avoid polluting the entity if possible

Answer (score 0):

Why not change your abstract class to a non-abstract one

```
class Parent {
    int Id { get; set; }
}
```

So you can instantiate it now and the behavior is the same.
Your abstract class is not behaving as an abstract one based on your example.

Comment: The example is contrived for brevity's sake. The class needs to be abstract